# C# generic constraint for base class and interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have some C# classes & interfaces that look something like this:

```
abstract Component { ... }
interface IA { ... }
interface IB { ... }

class ComponentA : Component, IA { ... }
class ComponentB : Component, IB { ... }
class ComponentAB : Component, IA, IB { ... }

abstract class Collection<T> where T : Component
{ 
    protected List<T> Items;
    ...  // Use Items as Component
}

class CollectionA : Collection<IA> 
{ 
    // Contains ComponentA and ComponentAB
    ... // Use Items as IA
} 

class CollectionB : Collection<IB> 
{ 
    // Contains ComponentB and ComponentAB
    ... // Use Items as IB
}
```

The problem here is the constraint on T on the Collection class. Code in Collection needs to use members of Component on the items, while code in CollectionA/B need to use members of IA/IB.

This currently doesn't compile because you can't pass IA/IB as a type parameter and also keep the type constraint on the base collection class.

I can't replace the interfaces with base classes because some of the components implement both interfaces. I don't want type casting because the whole point of having the collections, in this case, is to be an index for performance improvement, so casting has too much overhead.

Is there a way to define the type constraints to make this work, without using casting?

Comment: "to be an index for performance improvement, so casting has too much overhead" - What???

Comment: You must remove or change `where T : Component`. Otherwise you'll need to create `abstract class CollectionA<T> where T : Component, IA` & `abstract class CollectionB<T> where T : Component, IB`.

Comment: Type casting in a tight loop is bad practice and has a noticeable performance cost

Comment: You should provide a verifiable example of the noticeable performance cost.

Comment: Can you also give a reference supporting the statement "Type casting in a tight loop is bad practice"?

Comment: What issue specifically is the constraint causing?

Comment: The constraint prevents compiling as written, but we need it to access the Component members. Edited post to clarify.

Comment: _"This currently doesn't compile because you can't pass IA/IB as a type parameter and also keep the type constraint on the base collection class"_ -- well, `IA` and `IB` don't inherit `Component`. So if the constraint is a legitimate one in `Collection<T>`, you _shouldn't_ be able to use those types as parameters for `Collection<T>`. Please edit your question so that it explains why you think otherwise. Make sure you provide an actual [mcve] that fully illustrates your scenario.

Comment: Note that if you can change `CollectionA` (and `...B`) to be generic, you could do something like `class CollectionA<T> : Collection<T> where T : Component, IA`. But it's not clear from your question whether that would work in your scenario or not.

Comment: As I stated in the post, I'm aware the the constraint doesn't work, but it's there because we want to access members of Component in Collection.

Comment: Can you change Component to be an interface, and then derive IA and IB from that interface?  ComponentA would then just inherit IA, ComponentB would then just inherit IB, and ComponentAB would then just inherit IA and IB.

Comment: Making CollectionA/B generic doesn't work because ComponentAB can't implement two base classes, so there still isn't a type to pass to the constraint.

Comment: _"it's there because we want to access members of Component in Collection"_ -- wanting to do something isn't sufficient reason. There needs to be a type-safe way for it to actually work. If all you know about `CollectionA` is that it contains objects of type `IA`, you've got no business stuffing those arbitrarily into a `Collection<Component>`. That's what the compiler is telling you, and it's right.

Comment: I'm saying a want a way to tell the compiler that I know these objects are both Components AND they implement an interface, but not a base class that implements the interface

Comment: @RJM You are correct that changing Component to be an interface would solve the problem, but then it would be terrible for trying to share the code and implement all of the interfaces.

Comment: _"I know these objects are both Components AND they implement an interface"_ -- but your type system doesn't represent that. If you want the compiler to know that, you have to tell it, [as I've proposed in my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43905623/c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-base-class-and-interface#comment74845033_43905623)

Comment: @Peter Duniho I specifically already said that that doesn't work because of the ComponentAB case, it can't have 2 base classes.

Comment: @ExcelKobayashi - Can you please do an `@` response so that we know who you are responding to? Who were you replying to when you said, "I specifically already said that that doesn't work because of the ComponentAB case, it can't have 2 base classes."?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Your `ComponentAB` type would easily meet such a constraint for either `CollectionA` or `CollectionB`.

Comment: @Peter Duniho What I'm saying is that there isn't a type that you can put on the collection. There is no type to pass into the type constraint for CollectionA in your example.

Comment: @ExcelKobayashi - That's because your object model is broken. You're trying to make two wrongs and right. It doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean there's no type? If you constrain `class CollectionA<T> : Collection<T> where T : Component, IA`, then why can't you declare something like `CollectionA<ComponentA> collection;`?

Comment: @Peter Duniho because ComponentAB isn't a ComponentA. Even if it were a ComponentA, it couldn't also be a ComponentB at the same time, but it needs to be in both collections.

Comment: Ah, I see. You want to stuff elements of `ComponentA` and `ComponentAB` into your `CollectionA` class. I didn't notice that comment in your code at first. Well, like @Enigmativity has been saying, your object model is just plain broken in that case.

Comment: Why is it broken? Each of the components listed need to implement their respective interfaces. I want an index for the objects of each interface.

Comment: @ExcelKobayashi - if the suggestion to make Component an interface solves the problem with the inheritance model, then you could still do that and take another approach to solve the resulting code sharing problem.  For instance you could declare another class with the implemented methods and use an instance of that class internally in ComponentA, ComponentB, and ComponentAB in order to share the logic across those classes.  The downside is you do need to code a bunch of proxy methods on the three classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you fix this object model:

```
interface IComponent { }

abstract class Component : IComponent { }

interface IA : IComponent { }
interface IB : IComponent { }

interface IAB : IA, IB { }

class ComponentA : Component, IA { }
class ComponentB : Component, IB { }
class ComponentAB : Component, IAB { }

abstract class Collection<T1> where T1 : IComponent
{
    protected List<T1> Items;
}

class CollectionA : Collection<IA> { }
class CollectionB : Collection<IB> { }
class CollectionAB : Collection<IAB> { }
```

Comment: This is not typesafe in the way the OP requires.  One could easily declare a new fake class as `class FakeComponent : IA { }` and add an instance of it to `CollectionA`, despite the fact that FakeComponent is not derived from `Component`. But the OP required that `Collection` must use the items as `Component`.  This code does not enforce that constraint.

Comment: The change here is to use `IComponent` and not `Component` - that's what makes it work since interfaces can have multiple inheritance.

Comment: I understand, but it violates the OPs requirement that items in `Collection` must be instances of `Component`.  This solution does not enforce that.

Comment: @RJM - That's the point of this answer - his object model is broken so he can't have that constraint. Abandoning the `Component` constraint is the way to fix his model.

Comment: You're missing the point that there is no CollectionAB. ComponentAB is in both CollectionA and CollectionB, not in a separate collection. This is less type-safe, as pointed out above, but I think you are correct that creating IComponent fixes the core problem, as already pointed out by RJM

Comment: @ExcelKobayashi - Sure, just don't define `CollectionAB`.  `ComponentAB` implements both `IA` and `IB` so it'll work in either `CollectionA` or `CollectionB`.

Answer (score -1):

Provide an additional generic argument:

```
public abstract class Collection<TSource, TView> where TSource : Component, TView
{
    private List<TSource> _items;

    // This is the property that child classes will see.
    // It needs to be readonly because child classes can't insert TView elements
    protected IEnumerable<TView> Items { get { return _items; } }

    // ...
}
```

And then you'd extend it like this:

```
public class CollectionA : Collection<ComponentA, IA>
{
    // base.Items is IEnumerable<IA>
}
```

Comment: I believe you are the most persistent FGIW I've seen in a long time. That's what, four edits at least during your initial grace period? Maybe better to just wait until you really understand what the problem is before trying to come up with an answer?

Comment: This doesn't work because ComponentAB isn't a ComponentA

Comment: @ExcelKobayashi - That's not a problem with your model.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that allows for `class CollectionAB : Collection<ComponentAB, IA>` (which is clearly wrong). It also doesn't allow for a component being both `IA` & `IB`. To be fair the original object model is broken.

Comment: The original model isn't broken. ComponentAB needs to implement both interfaces. I could make it a ComponentA or a ComponentB, but it still wouldn't be possible to be both at the same time, so this solution doesn't work.

Comment: @ExcelKobayashi I think this is as far as you're going to get for compile-time safety

Answer (score -1):

I've been noodling on this a little more since commenting on the question above.

Instead of my original suggestion of making `Component` an Interface, I've left it as a class, but declared a new `ICommon` interface which `IA` and `IB` derive from.  I've also combined this with Matias Cicero's answer of having two generic arguments.  I think with all of these combined, it gives you what you want.  It does compile at least...

```
abstract class Component { }
interface ICommon {  }
interface IA : ICommon {  }
interface IB : ICommon {  }

class ComponentA : Component, IA {  }
class ComponentB : Component, IB {  }
class ComponentAB : Component, IA, IB {  }

abstract class Collection<T1, T2> where T1 : Component where T2 : ICommon
{ 
    protected List<T1> Items;
//    ...  // Use Items as Component
}

class CollectionA : Collection<Component, IA> 
{ 
    // Contains ComponentA and ComponentAB
//    ... // Use Items as IA
} 

class CollectionB : Collection<Component, IB> 
{ 
    // Contains ComponentB and ComponentAB
//    ... // Use Items as IB
}
```

Comment: This doesn't give the functionality that the OP is looking for. You could easily define a collection as `class CollectionBad : Collection<ComponentA, IB> ` which would just break stuff,

Comment: That wouldn't break anything.  You just wouldn't be able to add to the collection any instances of the existing classes that are defined in the current code, so it wouldn't make much sense to declare that.  But I believe this works and is typesafe for the OP's stated purpose.

Comment: It's not type-safe - you haven't included a way to return `List<T1> Items` as an enumerable of `T2` - if you did you see this breaks with `class CollectionBad : Collection<ComponentA, IB>`.

Comment: If the enumerable of `T2` were added and then causes the `CollectionBad` to not compile, isn't that a good thing?  We want invalid combinations of types to not compile.  Seems like this solution is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, but his solution has the constraint `where TSource : Component, TView` which ensures that `TSource` can be cast to `TView`. Your solution doesn't have that. In yours `T1` is unrelated to `T2` so it can't be cast.

Comment: Give it a shot and add in the enumerable and see if it works.

Comment: You'll get this error `CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T2>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`.